# How to program ATmega with fuses set to 32.768kHz clock?

Tags: avr, atmega, programmer, usbasp

I've been programming my ATmega328P's using USBasp programmer for a while. For my new project, I wanted to use 32.768kHz oscillator as an external clock, so I programmed the ATmega to appropriate fuses. Unfortunately, from this point on, I cannot communicate with the chip at all - avrdude tells me that target doesn't answer (rc=-1 error). After some research, I found some tips telling me to connect the oscillator (and capacitors) to chip's XTAL inputs, and then program the chip. I tried that, to no avail. Note that I also used avrdude's `-B 2000` switch, that slows down the programming as much as possible - to 500Hz, so programming speed shouldn't be an issue.

In a desperate attempt to rescue chip, I tried Arduino as ISP, but the results were pretty much the same.

Questions:

1. How to rescue this particular ATmega? Is high voltage programmer the only way out of this? I don't have one, so other options are welcome.
2. For the future: how should I program slow clock fuses so that I avoid this problem? It doesn't make sense for me - if programmer doesn't work with such fuses, why is there such a fuse setting in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got this.

It was much more stupid than I thought - I'm using a self-made programming board. Since I'm quite cheap, the same one is used for 28-pin ATmega's and 8-pin ATtiny's - they have MISO, MOSI and SCK in the same place (if I shift the chip two pins upwards), and the other pins (RESET, GND and VCC) don't conflict with each other. The thing is, I had modified my board to suit ATtiny's only recently, and this is the first time, I programmed an ATmega since then. It turns out, in my board, ATtiny's RESET does conflict with ATmega's oscillator input - so my oscillator, even if connected, was shorted to RESET, so it was unable to produce meaningful signal.

After desoldering that connection, everything works fine. I guess I'll just add a jumper for ATtiny programming and that's it.

Comment: Ha, turns out I even rescued my old ATmega this way - I thought I bricked it for some reason, but I randomly thought I'd connect it to my new circuit, and guess what - it had some clock fuse set too! Now it is back to normal.

Comment: (You may accept this answer so this question is not kicked to the main page (by the automatic process that does that)). Afterwards, you may flag this comment as "Obsolete").

Answer (score 1):

Even when fused to use a crystal, the ATmega328P will accept a clock signal injected into XTAL1 when being programmed by ISP. The USBasp does not provide such a signal so you will need to set up another circuit to generate a clock signal fast enough for programming.

The programmer should work with such a slow clock assuming the programmer uses a slow clock as well. Verify that the crystal operates normally.